# SetThreadAffinityMask use

Tags: c++, windows, timer

hey i would like to ask is this the  way to use SetThreadAffinityMask in first core? Thanks

```
void start()
uint64_t threadId = (uint64_t)GetCurrentThreadId();
    HANDLE handle = OpenThread(THREAD_ALL_ACCESS, false, threadId);
    SetThreadAffinityMask(&handle, 0x01);
    for (;;) {
        Xtimer MyRdtscTimer;
        MyRdtscTimer.Delay(1000000000);
    }
```

```
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        DisableThreadLibraryCalls(hModule);
        CreateThread(0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)&start, 0, 0, 0);
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

i tried GetCurrentThread but seems not working in my end

Comment: You aren't checking the return value of SetThreadAffinityMask function.

Comment: can you give more detail than `not working`? Note that you [shouldn't call `CreateThread` inside `DllMain`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-best-practices)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <windows.h>

void loadDataAsync(std::promise<std::string>& promise_data) {
   // Get the native handle of the current thread
   HANDLE thread_handle = ::GetCurrentThread();

   // Set the CPU affinity to the first processor (CPU 0)
   // for  (CPU 0 and CPU 1) use 3
   DWORD_PTR affinity_mask = 1;
   ::SetThreadAffinityMask(thread_handle, affinity_mask);
   // Start loading data asynchronously
   std::thread([promise_data]() {
   // Simulate loading data by sleeping for 3 seconds
   std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
   // Set the promise value to the loaded data
   promise_data.set_value("Loaded data");
 }).detach();
}

int main() {
   // Create a promise to hold the loaded data
   std::promise<std::string> promise_data;

   // Load data asynchronously
   loadDataAsync(promise_data);

   // Do some other work while the data is loading...
   std::cout << "Doing other work..." << std::endl;

   // Wait for the data to finish loading and retrieve it
   std::string data = promise_data.get_future().get();

   // Use the loaded data
   std::cout << "Loaded data: " << data << std::endl;

   return 0;
 }
```